# What can we say about the entire functions that omit the value zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

> What can we say about the entire functions that omit the value zero?

My thought:

Since any nonconstant entire function comes arbitrarily close to any complex number the said functions are either constant or comes arbitrarily close to zero.

Am I right?

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  What are the things that are said to be used for?  What sorts of things do you want to know?  As for your particular thoughts, yes, that is right.

Comment: The question is an exercise of the chapter "Application of Cauchy's Theorem"

Comment: Chapter of what?

Comment: http://books.google.com/books/about/Complex_variables_with_applications.html?id=GXQQRYUc7gQC

Comment: Thank you.  I haven't looked enough to see if the context makes clearer the type of things they want you to "say," but you've started with something sensible.  Another thing you could say is that if $f$ is an entire nonvanishing function, then there exists an entire function $g$ such that $\displaystyle{f=e^g}$.

Comment: Please clarify a li'l bit more how such $g$ can be obatained.

Comment: Sriti: See this other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88958/where-is-the-topology-hiding-in-this-theorem-on-entire-functions

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Very helpful reference!