# logarithm of an entire function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function (holomorphic over the complex plane). If $f$ has no zero point, then $\text{Log} f$ is also an entire function. How to prove this?

My idea: one branch of $\text{Log}f$ is well-defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \gamma$ for any $\gamma:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\gamma(\infty)=\infty$. Once it is well-defined, $\text{Log}f$ is holomorphic. By the open mapping theorem, $f(\mathbb{C})$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$. To show that $\text{Log}$ is well-defined on $f(\mathbb{C})$, we only need to show that $f(\mathbb{C})$ is simply-connected. But I do not know how to continue... Is a holomorphic function with no zero point a homeomorphism?

Since my way is inconvenient and problematic, is there any otehr ways to prove:

Let $f$ be an entire function (holomorphic over the complex plane). If $f$ has no zero point, then $\text{Log} f$ is also an entire function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88958/where-is-the-topology-hiding-in-this-theorem-on-entire-functions) question.

Answer (score 1):

We can find $\text{Log}\ f$ explicitely. Consider the function $g:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ such that $g(z)=f'(z)/f(z)$ since $f$ is non-zero and entire this function is also entire. Take the integral $\int_{0}^{z}g(\zeta) d\zeta$ along any path from $0$ to $z$. This is well defined since $f'/f$ is entire (hence every closed integral is zero). This integral is a branch of $\text{Log}(f)$.
Proof:
$$I=e^{\int_{0}^{z}g(\zeta) d\zeta}$$
$$I'=f'/f\cdot I$$
$$(I'f-If')/f^2=0$$
$$I=\text{constant}\cdot f$$
So, (this integral - some constant) is $\text{Log}\ f$

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics, where it has other meanings. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or `\times` ($\times$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Integrate $d\operatorname{Log} f$; that is, find a holomorphic $1$-form on $\mathbf{C}$ that "should" be $d\operatorname{Log} f$.

($\exp$ is entire, never zero, and not a homeomorphism, so your strategy, though natural, is problematic. In fact, constructing $\operatorname{Log} f$ using branches is rather inconvenient. :)

Comment: since my idea is problematic, how to prove the question?

Comment: There's a hint in my post, but as it happens, your question has been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88958/where-is-the-topology-hiding-in-this-theorem-on-entire-functions).